# How can I get ids of all ancestor nodes in XML, using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a large XML file that looks something like this:

```
<envelope>
  <headers>
  ...
  </headers>
<data>
  <Channel Id="303131" created="2016-06-02T14:01:00" modified="2016-06-02T14:01:00">
  <Fields />
  <Links>
    <ChannelNodes type="ChannelChannelNodes">
 ***  <ChannelNode Id="318630" created="2016-07-15T14:44:00" modified="2016-07-15T14:44:00" Index="0" LinkId="338254">
        <Fields />
        <Links>
          <ChannelNodes type="ChannelNodeChannelNodes">
 ***        <ChannelNode Id="303152" created="2016-06-02T14:29:00" modified="2016-08-31T11:14:00" Index="0" LinkId="338256">
              <Fields />
              <Links>
                <ChannelNodes type="ChannelNodeChannelNodes">
                  <ChannelNode Id="303155" created="2016-06-02T14:29:00" modified="2016-07-08T09:50:00" Index="0" LinkId="311083">
                    <Fields />
                    <Links>
                      <ChannelNodes type="ChannelNodeChannelNodes">
 ***                    <ChannelNode Id="303157" created="2016-06-02T14:29:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:08:00" Index="0" LinkId="311086">
                          <Fields />
                          <Links>
                            <ChannelNodes type="ChannelNodeChannelNodes">
                              <ChannelNode Id="303158" created="2016-06-02T14:29:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:09:00" Index="0" LinkId="311087">
                                <Fields />
                                <Links />
                              </ChannelNode>
 ***                          <ChannelNode Id="303159" created="2016-06-02T14:30:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:09:00" Index="1" LinkId="311088">
                                <Fields />
                                <Links />
                              </ChannelNode>
                              <ChannelNode Id="303160" created="2016-06-02T14:30:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:09:00" Index="2" LinkId="311089">
                                <Fields />
                                <Links />
                              </ChannelNode>
                            </ChannelNodes>
                          </Links>
                        </ChannelNode>
                        <ChannelNode Id="303161" created="2016-06-02T14:30:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:09:00" Index="1" LinkId="311090">
                          <Fields />
                          <Links />
                        </ChannelNode>
                        <ChannelNode Id="303162" created="2016-06-02T14:30:00" modified="2016-08-26T14:10:00" Index="2" LinkId="311091">
                          <Fields />
                          <Links />
                        </ChannelNode>
...etc
```

I need to find a way to list the IDs of all the ancestor nodes of a given id (I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology though). E.g. my input might be $id=303159, where my output should be $ids=[303157,303152,318630] (all relevant lines marked with ***).

It is quite possible that the input id would be found in different places in the same xml file at various depths. For instance, in the example above the input id has three ancestors, but it might as well have 1 ancestor in one place and 4 ancestors in another place in the same file. But the output I would need is just an array of all ancestors (1 ancestor + 4 ancestor would then give an array of 5 elements).

I guess I could do something like this:

```
$arr = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

and just use many foreach statements, searching for the right ID.
The problem with that is that it feels wrong, as I'm sure there is another way to do this and since the depth of the xml can change at any time (deepest level right now is 4 nodes, but it could be 8 in the future or any other number).

**Edit**

This is my current solution. It works on my current data, but it is not a good solution.

```
$arr = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
foreach($arr->data->Channel as $cn1) {
    $result[(string) $cn1->attributes()] = "allt";
    foreach ($cn1->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn2) {
    $result[(string) $cn2->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
        foreach ($cn2->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn3) {
            $result[(string) $cn3->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
            $result[(string) $cn3->attributes()][] = (string) $cn2->attributes();
            foreach ($cn3->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn4) {
                $result[(string) $cn4->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
                $result[(string) $cn4->attributes()][] = (string) $cn2->attributes();
                $result[(string) $cn4->attributes()][] = (string) $cn3->attributes();
                foreach ($cn4->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn5) {
                    $result[(string) $cn5->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
                    $result[(string) $cn5->attributes()][] = (string) $cn2->attributes();
                    $result[(string) $cn5->attributes()][] = (string) $cn3->attributes();
                    $result[(string) $cn5->attributes()][] = (string) $cn4->attributes();
                    foreach ($cn5->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn6) {
                        $result[(string) $cn6->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
                        $result[(string) $cn6->attributes()][] = (string) $cn2->attributes();
                        $result[(string) $cn6->attributes()][] = (string) $cn3->attributes();
                        $result[(string) $cn6->attributes()][] = (string) $cn4->attributes();
                        $result[(string) $cn6->attributes()][] = (string) $cn5->attributes();
                        foreach ($cn6->Links->ChannelNodes->ChannelNode as $cn7) {
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn1->attributes();
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn2->attributes();
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn3->attributes();
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn4->attributes();
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn5->attributes();
                            $result[(string) $cn7->attributes()][] = (string) $cn6->attributes();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a reverse-path [xpath](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) query.

```php
$lookForID = 303159;

$sXML = simplexml_load_string($xml, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$ancestorIdNodes = $sXML->xpath(
    "//ChannelNode[@Id=\"{$lookForID}\"]/ancestor::ChannelNode/@Id"
);

$ancestorIds = [];
foreach($ancestorIdNodes as $node) {
    $ancestorIds[] = (string) $node['Id'];
}

// $ancestorIds is an array of IDs you are looking for.
```

The actual xpath string can be read as: Get the Id attribute of any ChannelNode elements that are the ancestor of any ChannelNode within the tree whose Id attribute is equal to 303159.